# Tidy function is not working with USAboundaries shapefile data

Tags: r, broom

I'm not understanding what the error is as the `tidy` function works fine with other shapefiles, is `USAboundaries` missing something?

```
library(USAboundaries)
library(broom)

states_dat <- tidy(us_states(), region = "geoid")

##> states_dat <- tidy(us_states(), region = "geoid")
##Error in psych::describe(x, ...) : unused argument (region = "geoid")

head(us_states()[4],3)

##> head(us_states()[4],3)
##   geoid
##1     23
##2     15
##3     04
```

Comment: I don't know the `tidy()` function, but for what I can see the column names goes to one column named "column", and the other columns are some statistics of theses variables... Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`us_states()` returns an sf object. `tidy` has no method for `sf` objects and uses the `data.frame` method instead. On the other hand, `tidy` has methods for a variety of classes from the `sp` package, which may be why it "works fine with other shapefiles." (See `help(sp_tidiers)`.)

To use your existing code, you can convert the `us_states()` output to a `Spatial` object:

```
library(sf)
states <- as(us_states(), "Spatial")
states_dat <- tidy(states, region = "geoid")
```

To learn how to work with `sf` objects in a `tidy` framework, you may find http://strimas.com/r/tidy-sf/ helpful.